# Auth - register form redirects to profile - Web2py

Tags: python, authentication, authorization, web2py, web2py-modules

My problem is silly but I still can't find the answer.

I'm using auth functions of web2py but I'm customizing of what I need for example I created my own controller with my own functions using auth

Once I logged in , I want to create a new user but when I try to do so (users/newUser) the function redirects me to default/user/profile

I've tried changing the logged_url but doesn't work either =/

I also tried this `auth.is_logged_in = lambda: False` but obviously is wrong cause I'm losing the auth data .

```
def newuser():
    auth.settings.register_next = URL('nuevoUsuario',vars=dict(register='ok'))
    form = auth.register()
    return dict(form = form)
```

I hope you can help me ^^

Answer (score 0):

Add `auth.settings.register_next = URL('nuevoUsuario',vars=dict(register='ok'))` in `db.py`.

And edit controller:

```
def newuser():
    form = auth.register(next=auth.settings.register_next)
    return dict(form = form)
```

Not tested above solution!

Comment: @iyisus You may get some help from this https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/web2py/wKd5QN5R5fs

Answer (score 0):

Add
`auth.settings.register_next = URL('nuevoUsuario',vars=dict(register='ok'))`

In the `default.py` : `user()` function.

But just be aware that if you use email verification `auth.user` will be `None`, because no user is logged in.